# Inflation destination address

Tags: accounts, assets, inflation

1. Why do I have an inflation destination address and a public address?
2. What is the purpose of each?
3. Where do I find my inflation destination staking rewards?

Answer (score 0):

Inflation process is described [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html).

tl;dr: Inflation is not payed out to everyone but only to those accounts that are voted by others and reach a specific threshold (vote weight depends on voters XLM holdings). You can vote by setting your inflation destination. Of course you could vote for yourself (that's your public address btw), but you would need a pretty high stake to reach the threshold. An option would be to join an inflation pool ([lumenaut pool for example](https://pool.lumenaut.net/)) which will send your share directly to your public address.